# Lost item after sorting item in menu view

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I have problem with `UIActivity` function.

The first, I create 3 activity items:

1. `activityDownload`
2. `activityTrash`
3. `activityMove`.

And add to `UIActivityViewController`
And then, when I present `UIActivityViewController` which includes 3 items above. OK, no problem here.
Then, when I click button More, and sort items, ex, I move "Move" button to the top,
After click "Done" button, I don't know why Download, Trash items was lost?
Move items only displays in AirDrop menu view.

```
NSURL *url = [self fileToURL:self.documentName];
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[url];

AirDropActivityView *activityDownload = [[AirDropActivityView alloc] init];
activityDownload.airDropType = 0;
AirDropActivityView *activityTrash = [[AirDropActivityView alloc] init];
activityTrash.airDropType = 1;
AirDropActivityView *activityMove = [[AirDropActivityView alloc] init];
activityMove.airDropType = 2;

NSArray *uiActivitys = @[activityDownload,activityTrash,activityMove];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:uiActivitys];

// Exclude all activities except AirDrop.
NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypeMessage,UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

// Present the controller
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

https://gist.github.com/tranhieutt/f73999234339f31aa86c

Please see screen-shot:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be all your Custom UIActivity views you're using that having the same `activityType` will cause this problem.

So I recommend to create each more Custom `UIActivity` for each View you want to use. Like this:

Create `AirDropActivityView1`;
In `AirDropActivityView1.m`, implement:

```
#import "AirDropActivityView1.h"

@implementation AirDropActivityView

- (NSString *)activityType
{
    return @"youapp.Activity1";
}

- (NSString *)activityTitle
{
    return @"Activity1";
}

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

And with `AirDropActivityView2.m`

```
    #import "AirDropActivityView2.h"

    @implementation AirDropActivityView

    - (NSString *)activityType
    {
        return @"youapp.Activity2";
    }

    - (NSString *)activityTitle
    {
        return @"Activity2";
    }

    - (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
    {
        return YES;
    }

    @end
```

Finally:

```
    AirDropActivityView1 *activity1 = [[AirDropActivityView1 alloc] init];

    AirDropActivityView2 *activity2 = [[AirDropActivityView2 alloc] init];

    NSArray *uiActivitys = @[activity1,activity2];
```

Now you can reorder them.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thank for your help.
I just implemented. It's OK. So, I have more than 8 functions like that, it's mean i must create 8 class.

Comment: No, no need to. Create a general class, and how many view you want, create as many as instances for that. One thing you need keep in mind is that the `activityType` of each instance must be different.

Comment: > activityType of each instance must be different.
Yes, I understand.It's correct.
Thank you!